# Equivalent chromium version

Tags: google-chrome, chromium

I want to know the equivalent version of chromium for the 20.0.1132.47 m chrome version
Are there any way to know from wich chromium version is a given chrome version compiled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your OS:

[image: Chromium versions]

Source: http://peter.sh/experiments/latest-chrome-releases/

Comment: And in your link there is a link to http://omahaproxy.appspot.com/viewer where you can see the info that is updated from the chromium team (http://omahaproxy.appspot.com/about).

Comment: Not really sure, but they have registered updates up to yesterday so it seems it updates regularly.

Comment: Anyway, I can't found the 135598 chromium version in http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/chromium-browser-snapshots/index.html?path=Win/ that would be the equivalente to the 20.0.1132.47 on windows. I don't want to compile, I will try with the next chromium version

Comment: It looks like the page is broken. Is there an alternative?